# links does not show in my jssor slider embebed

Tags: jquery, slider, jssor

I have a slider in my web [grocery store](http://www.supermercadosoeste.com.uy) I put some links in an image but does not work on hover nor click

Comment: Great job! can I see your original slider on jssor.com?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `z-index: 10` from the following code in your style.css.

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    z-index: 10;
}
```